# Can I use JSON to indicate a person's presence status?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Our company has switched from onsite to cloud SharePoint, previously in the onsite SharePoint you could have a column that would display a person's presence status with a small traffic light icon next to the name. The cloud version only display's the name and requires you hover/click the name to pop-up a window that shows the presence icon.

I am now wondering whether I could use JSON formatting on the people/group column/field to pull the presence status from elsewhere and then JSON formatting to create the status color in the field?

Answer (score 1):

JSON formatting **does not support** showing presence of person or group column.

The people field object has the following properties only in JSON formatting (with example values):

```
{
   "id": "122",
   "title": "Kalya Tucker",
   "email": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "sip": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "picture": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kaylat_contoso_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63576928822",
   "department":"Human Resources",
   "jobTitle":"HR Manager"
}
```

---

In SharePoint online modern experience, presence is not shown directly in list view.

Presence will be shown on the persona card (with profile picture) when you hover over or click on person name, like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of the persona card limitation. I'm hoping to pull that presence status from the persona card, and use the value to "colour" a field (any field) using JSON to indicate presence status. I'm guessing that would only refresh each time the list is loaded, but that should be ok for my purpose. There must be some way to use JSON or a JAVA webpart to pull that presence status from "somewhere" to use it in a JSON script

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible using JSON formatting.

Comment: I'm currently looking at whether I use Power Automate to pull in the presence status which could then be used by JSON to colour code the presence of cells in a list. So I'm ready to put tools down on this one yet.

Comment: OK, even if you are able to pull the presence status using Power Automate, it will not be live/exact status, right? How often you will run this Power Automate flow? How many items (or unique users) you have in your list?

Comment: Hi Michael, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.